# JMS Serializer serialize object in object with diffrent view

Tags: symfony, serialization, fosrestbundle, jmsserializerbundle, jms-serializer

I'm developing a RESTful service with Symfony2, [JMS Serializer Bundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle), [FOS Rest Bundle](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSRestBundle) and [Hateoas Bundle](https://github.com/willdurand/BazingaHateoasBundle). There are 2 entities User and Company and I want to, when I serialize a Company get larger detail. 
But, when serializing User related Company show only Company ID and name object or just ID as integer.

I have serialize policy like below.

**User**

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
exclusion_policy: ALL
xml_root_name: user
properties:
    id:
        expose: true
        type: integer
    company:
        expose: true
        type: Acme\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company
    name:
        expose: true
        type: string
    surname:
        expose: true
        type: string
    picture:
        expose: true
        type: string
relations:
    -
        rel: self
        href:
            route: acme_v1_get_user
            parameters:
                id: expr(object.getId())
            absolute: true
```

**Company**

```
Acme\CompanyBundle\Entity\Company:
exclusion_policy: ALL
xml_root_name: company
properties:
    id:
        expose: true
        type: integer
    name:
        expose: true
        type: string
    address:
        expose: true
        type: string
    phone:
        expose: true
        type: string
    web:
        expose: true
        type: string
    created_date:
        expose: true
        type: DateTime
    updated_date:
        expose: true
        type: DateTime
    status:
        expose: true
        type: integer
relations:
    -
        rel: self
        href:
            route: acme_v1_get_company
            parameters:
                id: expr(object.getId())
            absolute: true
```

**Expected output**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jenny",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "picture": "http://google.com/kittens.jpg",
  "info": [],
  "company": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Demo Company"
  }
}
```

**OR**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jenny",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "picture": "http://google.com/kittens.jpg",
  "info": [],
  "company": 1
}
```

**What I got**

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jenny",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "picture": "http://google.com/kittens.jpg",
  "info": [],
  "company": {
    "id": 1,
    "name": "Demo Company",
    "address": "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet",
    "phone": "0902124440444",
    "web": "http://www.demo-company.com",
    "created_date": "2015-07-22T11:21:03+0300",
    "updated_date": "2015-07-24T01:50:39+0300",
    "status": 1
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use groups

```
AppBundle\Entity\User\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
        lastname:
            expose: true
            groups: [info]
```

And with an annotation, you can define which property is displayed on which group. And finally, you can assign a group to every route you use.

Or you can use virtual properties like so :

```
AppBundle\Entity\User\User:
    exclusion_policy: ALL
    properties:
         […]
    virtual_properties:
        getCompanyId:
            serialized_name: company
            type: string
            groups: [info]
```

And you create a `getCompanyId()` method in your User entity, that returns the companyId

Comment: Thank you, grouping work for me. I make a Default group which is for display every serialization process and a serialize owner related group eg. User group for user controller serialization or Company group for company controller. This way when I serialize from company activating company group so get full detail but from another company related serialization only shows default groups. 

Is there any better way to do this or this is common way for that?

Comment: I'm just beginning with serialization, so I don't know if there is a better way, but that's how I would do it

Answer (score 0):

The more Hateoas way to do it would be with the relations.

```
Acme\UserBundle\Entity\User:
exclusion_policy: ALL
xml_root_name: user
properties:
    id:
        expose: true
        type: integer
    name:
        expose: true
        type: string
    surname:
        expose: true
        type: string
    picture:
        expose: true
        type: string
relations:
    -
        rel: self
        href:
            route: acme_v1_get_user
            parameters:
                id: expr(object.getId())
            absolute: true
    -
        rel: company
        href:
            route: acme_v1_get_company
            parameters:
                id: expr(object.getCompany().getId())
            absolute: true
```

Would yield...

```
{
  "id": 1,
  "name": "Jenny",
  "surname": "Doe",
  "picture": "http://google.com/kittens.jpg",
  "info": []
  "_links": {
    "self": {
      "href": "http://server.com/api/user/1"
    },
    "company": {
      "href": "http://server.com/api/company/1"
    },
  }
}
```